# Rails 3 - How to Replace Existing Attachment in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have an invoice model.  When I create an invoice, an attachment is required.  This works.

How can I replace the attachment during an update?  I want the original attachment to be deleted.  When I have the same form field on the edit screen, it does not update upon submission.  The old file is still there.  Also, it shows "no file chosen", even though there is one.  I can click on View Attachment and it displays just fine.

invoice.rb

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :url => "http://...../attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_presence :attachment
  validates_attachment_size :attachment, :less_than => 5.megabytes
```

_form.html.erb

```
<label>Invoice Attachment: </label>
<%= f.file_field :attachment %>

<%= link_to 'View Attachment', @invoice.attachment.url %>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is call `update_attributes` or an equivalent, and paperclip will automatically delete the old attachment. For example, say you have this form (from the [paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start)):

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

In your controller you could have something like the following:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.update_attr(params)
end
```

Or, if you only wanted to update the attachment, you could do this:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  avatar_data = params.slice('avatar')
  @user = User.update_attr(avatar_data)
end
```

In either case, the old attachment will be deleted from storage, and the new file will take it's place.